# How to join modulo javascript [Native]

Tags: javascript, join, modulo

here is my js

```
while(i <= 25){
if (i % 4 === 0) {
  text += 'john';
}
else if (i % 5 === 0) {
  text += 'doe'
}
else if ((i % 5 === 0)&&(i % 4 === 0)){do something }
```

Multiples are both 4 and 5 print 'john doe'
I need to join modulo 5 and 4. Anybody help?
Thank you

Comment: Are those three somethings all the same somethings or different somethings?

Comment: please clarify what should happen when i === 1, 4, 5 and 20 - as it stands, the last else if can never be true

Answer (score 2):

```
while(i <= 25){
if ((i % 5 === 0)&&(i % 4 === 0)) {
  do something
}
else if (i % 5 === 0) {
  do something
}
else if (i % 4 === 0){ do something }
```

I hope it will help you.